# Order related entities in play framework

Tags: java, sorting, playframework, one-to-one

Let say I have two entity classes in play framework, java:

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model implements Validation {
    @Id
    private String email;
    private String password;
    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "userEmail")
    private Address address;}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Address extends Model{
    @Id
    @Column(name="userEmail")
    private String email;
    private String streetName;
    private String city;
    private String country;}
```

Now I want to retrieve all users from database and sort them based on streetName property of Address model. I used this `List<Restaurant> list = Restaurant.find.order("streetName asc").findList();`

but I get following error:

```
[PersistenceException: Query threw SQLException:Unknown column 'streetName' in 'order clause' 
Bind values:[]
```

If I put any User property as order string (`...order("email asc").findList();` ) it works and I get ordered list, but how can I make it order Users based on Address properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Restaurant.find.order("address.streetName asc").findList()`